# How to create three dependent dropdowns in Django, that the second is dependent on the first, and the third is dependent on the first and the second?

Tags: python, django, windows, pycharm, dropdown

In this program, the first dropdown is a field named education level, which is independent. Then there is a dropdown named field of study, which is related to the level of study. Then it has a dropdown called book, which is related to the first and second dropdown, which means the level of study and field of study.

It is expected that after selecting a education level and field of study, the book dropdown will bring only the list of books that are related to this degree and field of study.

Comment: Add your code so , we can edit it

Comment: You'll need AJAX, to POST the contents of the first two dropdowns back to the server and receive a list of books to display in the third. More a JS question than Django. Google "Django AJAX example"... take particular note of CSRFtoken handling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.